# Error while connecting to Snapdragon Profiler

Tags: android, profiler

I want to use the Snapdragon Profiler to debug an application on my rooted Android device. After enabling USB debugging and connecting it to the computer, the Snapdragon Profiler is unable to connect to the device, although pairing was successful: "There was an error while connecting to the device: Timed out waiting for a connection from target device. Please try connecting again."

It assume that it has something to do with tcpip connection, since Im also not able to connect to the device via: `adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555`. Im getting a `unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:5555: Connection refused`.

I’m able to connect non-rooted devices to the profiler though, but for the rooted one, neither a USB connection nor a wireless connection the PC will make the profiler connect to the device. Is there any way to run the Snapdragon Profiler for rooted devices?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost. Using that network address you will never be able to connect to your physical Android device. The command is for connecting to an emulator. Just connect your device via USB and install the correct drivers then you will not need a special connect command.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the clarification. I do have the correct driver running on my computer. I’m able to connect non-rooted devices to the profiler, but for the rooted one, neither a USB nor a wireless connection to the PC allows the profiler to connect.

Comment: Is the rooted device running a modified stock ROM or a custom ROM? If it is the latter then the cause may be some missing system components in the custom ROM.

Comment: @Robert Up to my knowledge I’m not running a custom ROM. My build number is `UP1A.231005.007.X900XXU5CLW1` which does not seem custom.

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model name of your rooted Android device?

Comment: @Robert Im using a Samsung Galaxy Tab S8 Ultra (SM-X900). Thanks for your effort